# Slicing an array in vba based on a condition

Tags: vba

I have an array of values in a VBAscript which are calculated from two ranges provided to the function.
I need to perform calculation on only a subset of the values in this array meeting a threshold condition.
So far I do have a working code:

```
Public Function CalculateCVar(exposure_v As Range, pdd_m As Range, a As Double) As Double
Dim ret_v_tail() As Double
Dim l, i As Integer

ret_v = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(exposure_v, _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(pdd_m))
value_at_risk = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Inc(ret_v, a)

l = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(ret_v)
    If ret_v(i) <= value_at_risk Then
        ReDim Preserve ret_v_tail(l)
        ret_v_tail(l) = ret_v(i)
        l = l + 1
    End If
Next i

CalculateCVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ret_v_tail)

End Function
```

However, I was wondering, if a better or more lean alternative exists to select a subset of an array in VBA meeting a certain condition, i.e. slicing the array based on a condition. Pseudo code would look like:

```
ret_v = [1., 2., 3., 4., 2., 4., 1., ...]
ret_v_tail = ret_v[ret_v <= 2.]
```

My current working code also has the drawback of being rather slow, as I have to use this function around 500 times for different input.

Comment: "a better or more lean alternative" - probably not. Not sure how much difference it makes but more efficient to redim your array to the max possible size and then slim down at the end rather than redim preserve every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redim Preserve` can be expensive, use it only twice (one at the beginning and one at the end)

for example you can use this function

```
Function GetTail(ret_v As Variant, value_at_risk As Double) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, iTail As Long

    iTail = LBound(ret_v)
    ReDim ret_v_tail(iTail To UBound(ret_v)) As Variant ' dim the tail to maximum possible items
    For i = iTail To UBound(ret_v)
        If ret_v(i) <= value_at_risk Then
            ret_v_tail(iTail) = ret_v(i)
            iTail = iTail + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve ret_v_tail(LBound(ret_v) To iTail - 1) As Variant ' redim tail to actual items number
    GetTail = ret_v_tail
End Function
```

to be called in your code as

```
ret_v_tail = GetTail(ret_v, 2#)
```

Comment: I am not sure why (I am not regular vba user), but I does not work with  ReDim Preserve ret_v_tail(0 To iTail - 1) As Variant but it does with  ReDim Preserve ret_v_tail(1 To iTail - 1) As Variant. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. And you're right: `ret_v_tail(iTail To iTail - 1)` was wromg since `Itail` at that point was already updated from its starting value of `LBound(ret_v)`. I edited the code. Thanks